# Mapbox get country/city name currently in view

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to get the country/city name depending on what is in view (in the center of the view) and the current zoom level in MapBox ?

For example when we are looking closely to Paris it return "paris" and when we zoom out we get "France".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use queryRenderedFeatures() you can get a array of all the features rendered in the current view. If you're at a scale with France in it, it will return a feature with the country_label id. If you zoom into Paris, you can find Paris with a place_label_city id. You can maybe parse the array to display what you want. You may have to pass in a mask layer like queryRenderedFeatures(layer)